# converting double array to json

Tags: javascript

I have an Array that looks like this

```
[["BR",1],["USA",2],["CH",3]]
```

and I want to convert it to something like this

```
{"br":1,"usa":2,"ch":3};
```

Any clues?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var len = arr.length, i, hash = {};
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  hash[arr[i][0].toLowerCase()] = arr[i][1];
}
```

This will convert into an object. You can use `JSON.stringify(hash)` in newer browsers, or if you use a library like jQuery, to make it into a JSON string. Writing JSON by yourself is somewhat error-prone, best leave it to builtins and libraries.

Comment: this seems to work, thanks Amadan! will accept the answer in just a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about just go ahead and do it?

```
    result = {};
    for( var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++ ) {
        result[theArray[i][0]] = theArray[i][1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the right answer!**

Here you go:

```
function toJSON($array) {
    if ($array.constructor !== Array) return false;
    var $res = {};
    for (var $subArray in $array) {
        for (var $k in $array[$subArray]) {
            $res[$k] = $array[$subArray][$k];
        };
    };
    return $res;
};

//Example
var test = [["BR",1],["USA",2],["CH",3]];
$JSON = toJSON(test);
```

The function will check type of the parameter, if it is an array, <strike>the function will scan and put them into an JSON object, then return it.</strike>

For some reasons, those code above return a really weird object, when I use for-in to loop it, it returns all methods/properties in Object constructor..

After a while trying, I finally come up with the more simple version, but other users had used it before I did. I don't know why but this time it took me a while before seeing the problem in the simple way (to realize that the each element of the array has only 2 length fixed).

```
function toJSON($array) {
    if ($array.constructor !== Array) { return false; };
    var $result = {};
    for (var $i = 0; $i < $array.length; $i++) {
        $result[$array[$i][0]] = $array[$i][1];
    };
    return $result;
};
```

I hope this help.

[x]

Comment: This won't actually work. Your test will print out {"0": "CH", "1": 3}.

Comment: You are correct, I saw the problems. Thanks for reminding me, I have come up with another one, but it seems like the same version with everyone else. [x]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
var arr = new Array(new Array('BR', 1), new Array('CN', 2));
var results = new Object();

for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    results[arr[i][0]] = arr[i][1];
}
console.log(results);
```